# why this way of executing python isn't working

Tags: python

```py
python -c 'for i in range(10): print i'
```

works, and

```py
python -c 'a=3;'
```

works, but

```py
python -c 'a=3;for i in range(10): print i'
```

gave an error

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    a=3;for i in range(10): print i
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone help point out why? Thank you.

Comment: The statement, python -c 'for i in range(10): print (i)' gives me error in python 3.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` can only be used to separate "simple" statements, not compound statements.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

```
compound_stmt ::=  if_stmt
                   | while_stmt
                   | for_stmt
                   | try_stmt
                   | with_stmt
                   | funcdef
                   | classdef
                   | async_with_stmt
                   | async_for_stmt
                   | async_funcdef
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
statement     ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | compound_stmt
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Because that's how Python syntax works. `for`, like all other statements that introduce an indent level, does not like having anything in front of it.

You need a newline in this case, not a semicolon. These are legal (assuming `bash`):

```
python -c 'a=3
for i in range(10)]: print(i)'

python -c $'a=3\nfor i in range(10): print(i)'
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed: Indeed, I should have said I'm using bash syntax to pass a newline as a part of `-c`. How you do that in `cmd` will differ (I don't speak `cmd`, can't tell you how to do that.)

Comment: Can i know, is it possible in `cmd`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed No idea, I don't touch the stuff. Maybe this? [How can I insert a new line in a cmd.exe command?](https://superuser.com/questions/150116/how-can-i-insert-a-new-line-in-a-cmd-exe-command/150120#150120)